# What in the world is Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where the user posts images into the database then when he presses a button he goes to a new VC. Then when viewDidLoad it should run a block of code (block 1) seen bellow. however when this happens i get many of the long error bellow in the console. What can i do about it and what does it mean?

> Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object gs:/practicearraybasicimg1.appspot.com/ZubvhhWV4PcYn5EeKHIVf1nQn213/post0/1536537585.03625.jpg/0.jpg does not exist." UserInfo={object=gs:/practicearraybasicimg1.appspot.com/ZubvhhWV4PcYn5EeKHIVf1nQn213/post0/1536537585.03625.jpg/0.jpg, ResponseBody=`NoSuchKey`The specified key does not exist.No such object: practicearraybasicimg1.appspot.com/gs:/practicearraybasicimg1.appspot.com/ZubvhhWV4PcYn5EeKHIVf1nQn213/post0/1536537585.03625.jpg/0.jpg, bucket=practicearraybasicimg1.appspot.com, data=<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2731 2e302720 656e636f 64696e67 3d275554 462d3827 3f3e3c45 72726f72 3e3436f 6463e4e 6f537563 684b6579 3c2f436f 64653e3c 4d657373 6167653e 54686520 73706563 69666965 64206b65 7920646f 6573206e 6f742065 78697374 2e3c2f4d 65737361 67653e3c 44657461 696c733e 4e6f2073 75636820 6f626a65 63743a20 79756269 70726163 74696365 61727261 79626173 6963696d 67312e61 70707370 6f742e63 6f6d2f67 733a2f79 75626970 72616374 69636561 72726179 62617369 63696d67 312e6170 7073706f 742e636f 6d2f5a75 62766868 57563450 63596e35 45654b48 49566631 6e516e32 31332f70 6f737430 2f313533 36353337 3538352e 30333632 352e6a70 672f302e 6a70673c 2f446574 61696c73 3e3c2f45 72726f72 3e>, data_content_type=application/xml; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object gs:/practicearraybasicimg1.appspot.com/ZubvhhWV4PcYn5EeKHIVf1nQn213/post0/1536537585.03625.jpg/0.jpg does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}

Block 1:

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        downloadImages(ImageObject: takePicViewController().image())
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + takePicViewController().postImage.numberPost)").child(ImageUploadManager().imageName)
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let childRef = ref.child("Posts").child(uid!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + takePicViewController().postImage.numberPost)")
        let postRef = childRef.child("ImageUrl")

        self.downloadImages(folderPath: "\(storageRef)", success: {
            (img) in
            print(img)
            self.p1ImageView.image = img
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

The function is as seen bellow:

```
func downloadImages(folderPath:String,success:@escaping (_ image:UIImage)->(),failure:@escaping (_ error:Error)->()){
for i in 0 ..< 194{
    // Create a reference with an initial file path and name
    let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\(folderPath)/0.jpg")
    reference.getData(maxSize: (3 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
        if let _error = error {
            print(_error)
            failure(_error)
        } else {
            if let _data  = data {
                let myImage:UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
                success(myImage)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: "what does it mean?"  Have you taken a good look at the error message for yourself?  It clearly says the file doesn't exist.  The path doesn't look right, either.

Comment: is the format of the reference wrong? Does it need to look exactly like what ot looks like in firebase? because when I look at the url on the database it has some extra string it seams after the .jpg But am not sure if that matters. Given that its a refrence URL to the imag ein storage

Comment: There is some metadata that will follow .jpg in the URL path after the file has been uploaded. When downloading it, don't use that 'extra' data (it doesnt look like you are). If you look at Block 1, where storageRef is defined, that's then passed to the downloadImages function which then appends another string to the end of it. It already ends with a child of imageName but then you're appending /0.jpg. That doesn't seem right. Trying adding a *print(reference)* right after the *let reference =* line and see what the ref resolves too.